# How to get all elements at indices stored in a vector?

Tags: r, indexing

I have a matrix where every row consists of zeros and a single one, say `y <- rbind(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,1,0))` and I have a vector holding indices for each row, say `x <- c(1,2,3)` and . Now I would like to count the number of times that `y[i,x[i]] == 1` holds. I know I could do this like

```
count <- 0
for(i in 1:3)
    count <- count + y[i, x[i]]
```

but I was interested if there would be a smarter way. Something like `count <- sum(y[,x])`. Of course this does not work, because `y[,x]` gives a matrix.

Therefore my question is there a way to get a vector with the elements at the positions given by another vector by using apply or any other smart trick, i.e. without `for`-loops?

I've already been looking for this, but I don't really know how to call this and therefore I didn't find anything useful. Apologies if this question already hangs around somewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing to extract the elements corresponding to 'x' and 'y' indices and then get the `sum`

```
sum(y[cbind(1:nrow(y), x)])
#[1] 2
```

If the values are different than 1,

```
sum(y[cbind(1:nrow(y), x)]==1)
```

---

Or for this case,

```
sum(diag(y)==1)
#[1] 2
```

Or

```
sum(y*diag(y))
```

EDIT: Changed the row/column index from `cbind(x,1:ncol(y))` to `cbind(1:nrow(y), x)` as per the comments.